# ARP IP Lookup, brings back nothing

Tags: arp

I have some weird things that just occured on my laptop, so I dropped down and did an ARP -a to capture external IP's and I get this, of which I can't seem to find the owners at all.  239.x.x.x is a public IP, how can it belong to no one?  Can someone explain what I'm missing?

```
Interface: myIP --- 0x15
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  239.192.1.209         01-00-5e-40-01-d1     static
  239.192.2.24          01-00-5e-40-02-18     static
  239.192.7.30          01-00-5e-40-07-1e     static
  239.192.7.189         01-00-5e-40-07-bd     static
  239.192.14.43         01-00-5e-40-0e-2b     static
  239.193.62.6          01-00-5e-41-3e-06     static
  239.193.62.16         01-00-5e-41-3e-10     static
  239.193.62.21         01-00-5e-41-3e-15     static
  239.195.204.1         01-00-5e-43-cc-01     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
```

Comment: Assigning names to IP addresses is purely optional.

Comment: No DNS?   I've seen No trace route, No ping..  You can usually at least find the owner of the DNS.